# FullCalendar Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined, even after I override start/end properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I'm using [FullCalendar 3](https://fullcalendar.io/), I changed the event property names to `start_at` & `end_at` instead of `start` & `end` by using the `startParam` & `endParam` like they said in the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) but it still don't work. Here is my JS :

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                locale: 'en',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                defaultDate: '2017-04-12',
                navLinks: true,
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true,
                events: {
                    startParam: 'start_at',
                    endParam: 'end_at',
                    url: '/products/all',
                    color: 'yellow'
                },
                eventRender: function(event, element) {
                    element.find('.fc-title').html(event.name);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The `url` accepts a JSON feed with this structure :

```
[
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Product 1",
                date: "2017-04-11",
                start_at: "2017-04-09 18:58:47",
                end_at: "2017-04-09 19:58:47",
                created_at: "2017-04-09 19:13:47",
                updated_at: "2017-04-09 19:13:47",
            },
        ...
]
```

The problem is that the events are displayed and using the `date` property defined in JSON instead of `start_at` or `end_at` as I defined, and if I remove it I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined`, even though I did define the `events` like this :

```
events: {
    startParam: 'start_at',
    endParam: 'end_at',
    //...
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be that [startParam](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/startParam/) and [endParam](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/endParam/) value must be **ISO8601 string date format** (as a doc says).

I think the datetime of your example is not acceptable by the ISO8601.
Try to change it.

I hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have my events in ISO8601 string date format and I have the same issue...